# How to get all reviews in themoviedb api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, express

I am creating a rest api , I would like to retrieve or get all reviews/comments which are in a database.

This is what I have done :

```
app.get('/review', (req, res) =>{
        request('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/review?api_key=4d9c9de3bdf0d3b6837c49c086e3b190', function (error, response, body) {
            console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred and handle it
            console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
            res.send(body)
          });
    });
```

I am getting this error: 
`{"status_code":34,"status_message":"The resource you requested could not be found."}`

what am I doing wrong here?  help

Note: other methods works perfectly

Comment: its just testing api nothing special

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a JS error or anything. If you look at the [API Documentation](https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api/status-codes), `status_code: 34` means you're accessing an endpoint that *doesn't exist*.

Diving into the docs a bit further, you can't get ALL the reviews in the database. All you can do is get the reviews on a *per movie* basis. Try this URL:

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/401478/reviews?api_key=4d9c9de3bdf0d3b6837c49c086e3b190
```

Here's the documentation on the `/movie/<movie_id>/reviews` endpoint: https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-movie-reviews

There is also the `/review/<review_id>` end point, but it appears that gets a single review by id which probably isn't what you're looking for:
https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/reviews/get-review-details

Comment: I have one more simple question: Post/Movies: Based on passed title, other movie details should be fetched from thememoviedb,  what is the simple way to accomplish this i am able to create new data using known post method , can you help on this?

Comment: I have another question bro if you can hekp here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50858647/mongoerror-filter-parameter-must-be-an-object/50864643?noredirect=1#comment88735870_50864643  can you check it out?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anything about Express or MongoDB/Mongoose - I'm not sure I can be of any help on that one.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with `nodeJS`.As stated by @VicJordan, the problem is only with the `url` you are trying to search, it's simply not a valid API request. Try to go thru [API documentation](https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api) to find out how to use them. An example of a valid URL would be:

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=4d9c9de3bdf0d3b6837c49c086e3b190
```