# MongoError: filter parameter must be an object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am creating a rest api I have end point for Post/Movies: Request body should contain only movie title, and its presence should be validated Based on passed title, other movie details should be fetched from thememoviedb,and saved to application database.

```
app.post('/movies', (req, res) => {
        request('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK&sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=2931998c3a80d7806199320f76d65298', function (error, response, body) {
            console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred and handle it
            console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received

          });
        db.collection('movies').findOneAndUpdate(req.body.title,{
            title: 'Avengers',
        },(err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                res.send({
                    'error': 'An error has occured'
                });
            } else {
                res.send(result.ops[0]);
            }
        });
});
```

when I run the app I get this error, what am I doing wrong here,? am new to nodejs and all this stuff just learning

Comment: `req.body.title` is not an "object". Actually it looks like a typo as the next thing `{  title: 'Avengers'   }` is what you mean. Or probably `{ title: req.body.title }`. In short, it looks like you forgot to remove your test and added the variable in the wrong place.

Answer (score 4):

Use `$eq` operator in the filter object [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/)

```
{ <field>: { $eq: <value> } }
```

So the final snippet becomes like this:

```
app.post('/movies', (req, res) => {

    /* code ... */

    let { title } = req.body

    db.collection('movies').findOneAndUpdate({ title: { $eq: title } }, { title: 'Avengers' }, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send({ 'error': 'An error has occured' });
        } else {
            res.send(result.ops[0]);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: when I run localhost: 8000/movies i get errror in  console TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined , in post man , could not get any rensponse.

Comment: Try `console.log(result)` to see how the JSON is structured

Comment: This is what I get : `We are live on 8000
{ lastErrorObject: { updatedExisting: false, n: 0 },
  value: null,
  ok: 1 }
error: null
statusCode: 200`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

```
db.collection('movies').findOneAndUpdate({title:req.body.title},{
          $set:{
           'Avengers'
          }})
```

Comment: Unexpected Token , } ?

Comment: probably i have not closed it properly, check the closing { in your code

Comment: something is not right with set method, check it again if that is the right way of doing it , closing brackets all good

Comment: https://github.com/freespiritdev/Media/blob/d7d21e4145c28f6437ccfd6b2cb4abda04ea31e4/server/server.js

Comment: did the answer help?

Comment: I went ti sleep I will check it up :)

Comment: @HotZellah did it help?